# Use data to define amount of objects in Array

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm working on a checklist in SwiftUI and want to define the amount of checkboxes in my data. So for example, in case of fruit, the user should tick 3 checkboxes whereas water requires more checks because you need to drink more glasses of water a day.

I'm using "for each" in a HStack to make an array of checkboxes:

```
 HStack {
           ForEach(0 ..< 3) { index in
           VStack {
               Button(action: {
                  self.checked[index].toggle()
                                    })
```

I want to replace the **( 0..<3)** with **checklist.steps** which is where the amount (INT) is defined.

```
let checklistData = [
    Checklist(title: "Fruit", instruction: "1 vakje = 1 stuk of 100g", steps: Int(4)),
```

Is there a way to define the amount of checkboxes in my data?

Thanks in advance <3

**Solution**

The following code worked for me:

```
HStack {
           ForEach(0 ..< checklist.steps) { index in
           VStack {
               Button(action: {
                  self.checked[index].toggle()
                                    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, here my better answer, thanks for your code:

```
struct ChecklistView: View {
    var checklist: Checklist
    @State var currentProgress: Float = 0.0
    @State var checked = \[false, false, false, false\]


    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {

            //            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
            //                .foregroundColor(.red).opacity(0.5)
            //                .frame(width: 200)

            VStack {
                HStack(alignment: .top) {
                    checklist.image
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                        .padding(.trailing)
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(checklist.title)
                            .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .medium))
                            .padding(.bottom, 4)

                        Text(checklist.instruction.uppercased()).font(.system(size: 12))

                        HStack {
                            ForEach(0 ..< checklist.steps) { index in
                                VStack {
                                    Button(action: {
                                        self.checked\[index\].toggle()
                                    }) {
                                        ZStack {

                                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                                                .foregroundColor(self.checked\[index\] ? Color("LightGreen") : .gray )
                                                .frame(width: 40, height: 40)

                                            Image(systemName: self.checked\[index\] ?  "checkmark" : "plus")
                                                .resizable()
                                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                                .frame(width: 16, height: 16)
                                                .foregroundColor(self.checked\[index\] ? .white : .white)

                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }.frame(width: 350, alignment: .leading)
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 350)
        .padding(.bottom, 16)
        .cornerRadius(8)
        .padding(.top, 20)
    }
}

// MARK: data checklist
struct Checklist: Identifiable, Hashable {

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
        hasher.combine(title)
    }

    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var title: String
    var instruction: String
    var image: Image
    var steps: Int
}



struct ContentView: View {

    let checklistData = \[
        Checklist(title: "Fruit", instruction: "1 vakje = 1 stuk of 100g", image: Image("kiwi"), steps: Int(4)),
        Checklist(title: "Fruit", instruction: "1 vakje = 1 stuk of 100g", image: Image("kiwi"), steps: Int(2))

    \]

    var body: some View {
        List(checklistData, id: \.self) { checkList in
            ChecklistView(checklist: checkList)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Chris! I've updated the full code above. Still getting errors because of home view. Do you know what's going on? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: When you click a plus, the whole row's plus become checkmarks with your code.

Comment: @JoëlvanBodegraven, you are probably getting errors because there are extraneous backslashes

Comment: So after adding this `ForEach(0 ..< checklist.steps)` to the code it worked!! Thanks everyone!!

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure whether you want this?

```
HStack {
       ForEach(0 ..< checklistData[x].steps) { index in
       VStack {
           Button(action: {
              self.checked[index].toggle()
                                })
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I get the following error: "Use of unresolved identifier 'x'"

Comment: i thought you know how to fill x yourself, if not, please show us all your code so i can help you.

Comment: Hey Chris, I've added the full code. I'm new to Swift so still figuring out lots of stuff. Thanks for your help!